Persist a manually added WireGuard IP route in Asus RT-AX58U Router
I have a couple of Asus RT-AX58U routers with a WireGuard VPN between them.  Router "B" connects to router "A".  The LAN address for Router "B" is 192.168.50.1/24, while router "A" is 192.168.0.1/24.  The WireGuard VPN tunnel network is 10.5.0.0/8 with "B" at 10.5.0.2 and "A" at 10.5.0.1.  The VPN works just great - machines connected to the LAN side of Router "B" can see machines on the LAN side of Router "A", and vice-versa.  The only machine that can't be reached from the LAN side of Router "A" is the management interface of router "B", making it very difficult to remotely manage router "B".  Manually adding a route back to 192.168.0.0/24 in router "B" allows that to work.
I can create a route in router "B" such that requests originating from 192.168.0.0/24 are routed correctly back to the source.  If I SSH into router "B" and add the following route, packets from machines on 192.168.0.0/24 sent to Router "B" arrive back at the source machine correctly:
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.5.0.1

However, if router "B" is rebooted, the route is missing on reboot.
How do I persist the route?
I understand the /jffs filesystem is writable and persisted, so I could create a script there, but how do I get that script to run at startup, after the WireGuard VPN comes up automatically at boot?

FYI, /Advanced/GWStaticRoute_Content.asp on the web admin page for Router "B" allows adding persistent routes, however specifying the WireGuard interface is not an option - the only options are LAN, MAN, and WAN - none of which allow the route to correctly route packets via the WireGuard virtual interface.

It looks like I might be able to add a PostUp script to the WireGuard configuration for the client, per the details at https://github.com/pirate/wireguard-docs?tab=readme-ov-file#PostUp
PostUp

Optionally run a command after the interface is brought up. This option can appear multiple times, as with PreUp

Examples

    Read in a config value from a file or some command's output
    PostUp = wg set %i private-key /etc/wireguard/wg0.key <(some command here)

    Log a line to a file
    PostUp = echo "$(date +%s) WireGuard Started" >> /var/log/wireguard.log

    Hit a webhook on another server
    PostUp = curl https://events.example.dev/wireguard/started/?key=abcdefg

    Add a route to the system routing table
    PostUp = ip rule add ipproto tcp dport 22 table 1234

    Add an iptables rule to enable packet forwarding on the WireGuard interface
    PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

    Force WireGuard to re-resolve IP address for peer domain
    PostUp = resolvectl domain %i "~."; resolvectl dns %i 192.0.2.1; resolvectl dnssec %i yes

So, theoretically, if I create a script at /jffs/add_route.sh containing the desired route add command, the WireGuard client should automatically create the route whenever the VPN link comes up.
